# Consuming chunked data asyncrhonously in javascript

Tags: javascript, http, asynchronous, http-streaming

I have a (GET) endpoint that sends data in chunks ([`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding)). The data is JSON encoded and sent line by line.

Is there a way to consume the data sent by this endpoint in an asynchronous manner in JavaScript (or using some JavaScript library)?

To be clear, I know how to perform an asynchronous `GET`, but I would like to have the `GET` request not waiting for the whole data to be transfered, but instead read the data line by line as it arrives. For instance, when doing:

```
curl  http://localhost:8081/numbers
```

The lines below are shown one by one as they become available (the example server I made is waiting a second between sending a line and the second).

```
{"age":1,"name":"John"}
{"age":2,"name":"John"}
{"age":3,"name":"John"}
{"age":4,"name":"John"}
```

I would like to reproduce the same behavior `curl` exhibits, but in the browser. I don't want is leave the user wait till all the data becomes available in order to show anything.

Comment: The future answer would likely be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API

Comment: Thanks! That's why I cannot find an answer to this problem anywhere.

Comment: Well Streams_API doesn't look like coming to Firefox anytime soon but [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) is already available with [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). You might find [this article on how to handle streams with Fetch 
 API](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/#streams) interesting.

Comment: Damn! I wish I had seen your answer before re-implementing the end-point to use server sent events :) I'm gonna give `ReadableStream` a try.

Comment: Right, you may save some workload and a websockets library dependency at the server side.

Comment: The good news I have a working version of this! The bad news: it only works on Chrome (Firefox 58 will give the `TypeError: response.body is undefined`).

Comment: This isn't valid `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` stream format. It's missing the chunk length.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388787/dan-d) and [Redu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4543207/redu) I was able to put together an example that consumes data incrementally, using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) . The caveat is that this will not work on Internet Explorer, and it has to be enabled by the user in Firefox:

```
   /** This works on Edge, Chrome, and Firefox (from version 57). To use this example
    navigate to about:config and change

    - dom.streams.enabled preference to true
    - javascript.options.streams to true


    See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream
*/

fetch('http://localhost:8081/numbers').then(function(response) {

  console.log(response);

  const reader = response.body.getReader();

  function go() {
    reader.read().then(function(result) {
      if (!result.done) {
        var num = JSON.parse(
          new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(result.value)
        );
        console.log(
          "Got number " + num.intVal
        );        
        go ();
      }
    })
  }

  go ();
})
```

The full example (with the server) is available [at my sandbox](https://github.com/capitanbatata/sandbox/tree/66048994a3ecc00e241ce8107cce388b7a266222/streaming-endpoints). I find it illustrative of the limitations of `XMLHttpRequest` to compare this version with the [this one](https://github.com/capitanbatata/sandbox/blob/66048994a3ecc00e241ce8107cce388b7a266222/streaming-endpoints/examples/users-no-stream.html), which does not use the `fetch` API.

Comment: Glad to see that you have worked it out with the `ReadStream`. Just one quick reminder; unlike in Haskell, in JS using recursion in production code might turn out to be hazardous since your call stack might get blown up eventually if you have like 200K+ chunks to read. So if you know the chunk count in advance you might as well fill an array of that size with `reader.read()` promises and then chain their `.then()` stages up by  reducing the array, sequencing the promises. Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder Redu. I spent too much time doing Haskell :)

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee that the `body` stream will give you the full chunks in one read (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412098/does-fetchs-response-body-chunks-correspond-to-http-chunks). You might be better off using NDJSON (buffering the decoded text until you hit a newline, then parsing the JSON in the buffer up until then).

Comment: @Vidar your answer pretty much covers every use case, but i have a hard time applying ndjson parsing to my reader, do you have any usage sample?

Comment: @moxched This might be of some assistance: https://github.com/deanhume/streams

Comment: As already mentioned, this fails to handle multiple received chunks in one read or partially read chunks.