# JS Fetch use Chunked Transfer Encoding (translating curl to Fetch)

Tags: javascript, curl, fetch

I'm trying to convert this curl command from the Kaldi docs:

```
curl -v -T test/data/english_test.raw -H "Content-Type: audio/x-raw-int; rate=16000" --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" --limit-rate 32000  "http://localhost:8888/client/dynamic/recognize"
```

To JS code, specifically fetch. I'm able to POST a binary file using fetch pretty easily but specifically what I need to do is use chunked transfer encoding. To the life of me I can't find any docs on this, and as far as I know in JS, it's really up to the user agent to set the transfer encoding. Would appreciate any pointers!

Comment: I don't think `Fetch` gives you this level of control.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49211413/441757

Comment: @sideshowbarker so there's a lot on _consuming_ the data but I'm not worried about the response (the response only comes in the last chunk to begin with so it suffices to treat it as a normal response), specifically I need to send the request body in chunks

Comment: Ah OK then maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939857/fetch-with-readablestream-as-request-body and https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/pull/425. So the Fetch spec provides a way to do this (create a request from a Request made from a ReadableStream), but unfortunately, I don’t think any browsers have shipped it yet.

Answer (score 0):

this is your js fetch req :

```js
fetch('http://localhost:8888/client/dynamic/recognize', {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'audio/x-raw-int; rate=16000',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
  },
  body: File(['<data goes here>'], 'test/data/english_test.raw')
});
```